# wget и редирект

Tags: wget

Есть к примеру сайт http://goodmoons.ru/land_dc12v-1
используя команду: 
`wget -r -k -l 7 -p -E -nc -m http://goodmoons.ru/land_dc12v-1` 
не получается скачать сайт, а лишь страничку с яваскриптом.
Можно ли обойти это?

Comment: а можно ли еще как-то скачивать ссылки с двойным слешем вначале? ...src="//static...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зайдите на сайт и полученные в своем браузере куки подставьте в wget и useragent не забудьте.

Comment: Спасибо! Получилось